# Transposing rows to columns in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

how can I transpose one spark DataFrame in such a way:

From:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Key1 | Value1 |
| Key2 | Value2 |
| Key3 | Value3 |

TO:

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly provide a minimal reproducible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html) operation to transpose rows to columns.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("Key1", "Value1", ),
("Key2", "Value2", ),
("Key3", "Value3", ), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Key", "Value", ))

df.groupBy().pivot("Key").agg(F.first("Value")).show()

"""
+------+------+------+
|  Key1|  Key2|  Key3|
+------+------+------+
|Value1|Value2|Value3|
+------+------+------+
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

[pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html)

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('key1','value1'),('key2','value2'),('key3','value3')], ['key', 'value'])
```

---

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupBy().pivot('key').agg(F.first('value')).show()
```

or

```
df.groupBy().pivot('key').agg({"value":"first"}).show()
```

---

```
+------+------+------+
|  key1|  key2|  key3|
+------+------+------+
|value1|value2|value3|
+------+------+------+
```